# How to know if my data follow two parameters or three parameters lognormal distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, normal-distribution

Please I need help. I am working on dilution of pollutants and I have carried out experiment and obtained my data as in the code below;

```
set.seed(123)
sample1 = runif(1500, 0.14,0.26)
sample2 = runif(1500, 0.14,0.26)
sample3 = runif(1500, 0.14,0.26)
sample4 = runif(1500, 0.14,0.26)
sample = data.frame(sample1,sample2,sample3,sample4)
sample_product = sample$sample1*sample$sample2*sample$sample3*sample$sample4
Sample = cbind(sample,sample_product)
c4 = Sample$sample_product*360.5
Data = cbind(Sample,c4)
```

Now, I want to know if c4 follow a two parameters lognormal distribution or a three parameters lognormal distribution. I have searched online and all what I got is how to obtain the estimate of the parameters. Your help will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Try to check this package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lognorm/lognorm.pdf.

Comment: This is off topic for SO, try stats.stackexchange.com instead. The basic answer is that no real data fit any theoretical distribution, so it is always a question of what fits better, also taking into account what is considered plausible a priori. This is most accurately summarized by "Bayesian model selection". However, a reasonable approximation is to just look at a range of plausible models and see which one has the greatest log likelihood.

Comment: In the case of nested models, as you have here, you can always get a better fit by including one or more additional parameters, so you'll have to look at whether the increase in log likelihood justifies the more complex model -- this is essentially a judgement call.